# How to use AspNetCore 3.0 features/components in a class library project

Tags: asp.net-core, class-library

We have some class libraries that provide common functionality for our internal software. Some of these have references to AspNetCore libraries. For instance we have a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization` v2.x.x to use the `AddAuthorization` extension method on `IServiceCollection`.

Now that we're migrating our projects to dotnet core 3.0 we've found that many of these types are changed or no longer exist. This leads to runtime exceptions when using our packages. Initially we thought we just needed to upgrade the various NuGet packages to their 3.x.x variants... but these don't exist!?!

We run into the same problem with implementations of `IFilter` and other MVC interfaces/classes.

How should we use these types in class libraries now?

Comment: I assume you did look at the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Yes, but it starts with updating the `TargetFramework` to `netcoreapp3.0`, but if I do that, it won't be a netstandard class library anymore. Perhaps I'm just confused as to how this stuff is supposed to work...

Comment: Ah ok. Would that be netstandard2.1? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Core 3 most of the packages are moved into the framework, so referencing the framework may solve your problem:

```xml
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp3.0'">
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: For myself and others, this blog post by Andrew Lock describes various upgrade scenario's in detail: https://andrewlock.net/converting-a-netstandard-2-library-to-netcore-3/